# Indentação automática no VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como resolver essa falta de indentação automática do VSCode. Eu queria que, ao apertar enter, o código ficasse automaticamente indentado.

Antes ele indentava certinho, já no ponto pra continuar, porém agora preciso dar mais um enter e tab pra poder continuar o código.

Answer (score 0):

Tente Ctrl+Shift+P no VScode, procure nas opções por **Preferences: Open User** Settings, digite na caixa de pesquisas **indent**, na parte de **Editor: Auto indent** escolha a opção full

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. En contrei. alterei pra full, mas segue sem indentar. E isso tá acontecendo somente nos arquivos css e js.